# Trying to write to csv from input , csv output file shows each name with colons between letters and emtpy line in 1 row

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv 
n = int(input("How many records ?"))
b = 0
for i in range(n):


   s = input("what is the name of the student  ")
   g = input(" grade ?")
   k.append(s),k.append(g)
 print("res",'[%s]'%', '.join(map(str, k)))

StuGrade = "StuGrade.csv"
with open(StuGrade, 'w' ) as f :
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow( k[0])
    for i in range(n*2-1) :
        b=b+1
        thewriter.writerow( k[b])
```

This is the output of my program:

> ```
> How many records 1
>
> what is the name of the student  ahmad 
>  grade ? 3
> res [ahmad ,  3]
> ```

The csv file looks like this:

> a,h,m,a,d,
>
> ,3

I want it like that:

> ahmad
> 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv.writerow()` takes a list of values for that row - you are supplying single values. Strings are iterables - if you give one string to `csv.writerow()` it will use every single letter as 1 column. You could fix that supplying it as 1 element list:

```
 thewriter.writerow( [ k[b] ] )  # 1 element list
```

To write a csv correctly (with single or with multiple values per row and multiple rows) you are missing a `newline=""` when opening the file (this is well documented) to create the csv file correctly - missing this introduces the empty line in your current output.

```
with open(StuGrade, 'w', newline = "") as f :  # add  newline = ""
```

You do not really need a csv writer to create a file with 1 thing per line:

```
with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    for word in k:               # dont use index iterating, use element itering
        f.write(word + "\n")
```

would do it.

---

Fix/Demo for 2 values per line:

```
import csv 

k = ["ABC","5", "BCD","7", "CDE","42"]

StuGrade = "StuGrade.csv"
with open(StuGrade, 'w', newline = "") as f :  # added newline
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    # go over the range of input indexes and increase by 2       
    for idx in range(0, len(k), 2):
        # slice and write 2 values as 2 columns from your k list at once 
        thewriter.writerow( k[idx : idx+2]) 

print(open("StuGrade.csv").read())
```

Output:

```
ABC,5
BCD,7
CDE,42
```

Comment: @ahmad for 1 item per line don't use csv - instead use `with open("file.txt","w") as f: for word in k: f.write(word + "\n")` - or use `thewriter.writerow( [ k[b] ] )` if you have an assignment forcing you to use `csv`